# jQuery select by data-attribute AND :last-child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully this should be fairly simple to some of you JS experts out there!

Ok, so I have various `<section>` tags, which have a `data-week` attribute. Each section also has a `data-date` attribute.

I need to get the last section grouped by `data-week` for any given week, so I can check if the date was earlier this week, or still to come.

I get 2 results when I do this:

```
let sections= $('section[data-week="' + thisWeek + '"]');
```

I only need the last one. I tried to add `:last-child` like this:

```
let lastSectionOfThisWeek = $('section[data-week="' + thisWeek + '"]:last-child');
```

But that didn't return a thing. How can I use both together to get the last section with my week number?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure why that wouldn't work. Can you include some markup and create a [MCVE]? Also, you could try jQuery's [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) method or the `:last` selector.

Comment: Try just `:last`. Failing that, please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:last-child` means *the last child* not *the last child which also matches the rest of the selector*.

Given: `<a /><a /><b /><b />` then `b:last-child` will match the last `b`, as will `:last-child` but `a:last-child` won't match anything because neither of the `a` elements is the last child.

Just get all the elements, and then [pluck the last one off the set](https://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
let lastSectionOfThisWeek =  $('section[data-week="' + thisWeek + '"]').last();
```

or use [the jQuery-specific `:last` filter](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/#last1):

```
let lastSectionOfThisWeek =  $('section[data-week="' + thisWeek + '"]:last');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) which reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set:

```js
let thisWeek = "1";

let lastSectionOfThisWeek = $('section[data-week="' + thisWeek + '"]').last();

console.log(lastSectionOfThisWeek.text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section data-week="1" data-date="10/10">
  Section 1
</section>
<section data-week="1" data-date="10/11">
  Section 2
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector:

```js
var thisWeek = "week";

console.log($(`section[data-week=${thisWeek}]:last`).attr("id")) // third
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="first" data-week="week">First</section>
<section id="second" data-week="week">Second</section>
<section id="third" data-week="week">Third</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

While sections is array so you can get the last value by this way

```
let sections= $('section[data-week="' + thisWeek + '"]');
let lastsection= sections[sections.length-1];
```

Comment: so the second line is the pure javascript way to do it?

Comment: Yes it is the pure JavaScript way